# Amazon ad widget

Tags: ads

I am trying to add a couple of ad widgets to my website http://yankeedesi.com. Please see the two widgets in the right panel. I created the widgets using the amazon associates interface and it showed up fine. However, when I try to change the style to gallery and transition to zoom and save it, the changes are not reflecting in my site. I am clicking on "Save" and then "Add to my webpage". I tried copying the generated code again (which looks the same as before) but even that did not work.

Even the new products I added are not reflected. Creating it afresh will probably work but I am experimenting with the style, and also intend to add/remove products on an ongoing basis, so every time I change something I don't want to recreate the widget. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Have you republished your widget after the changes you have made as it is [described in here](https://affiliate-program.amazon.co.uk/gp/associates/help/t23/a6/279-1665829-1891952?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_i=assoc_help_t24&pf_rd_m=A3P5ROKL5A1OLE&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-2&pf_rd_t=501)?

UPDATE: (from OP's comment) I checked with their customer support and understand it is a known bug in their system. The workaround is to copy it to a new widget and delete the previous one. That works but is a tedious process if you have to make the changes frequently

Comment: Yes, I have. I checked with their customer support and understand it is a known bug in their system. The workaround is to copy it to a new widget and delete the previous one. That works but is a tedious process if you have to make the changes frequently :(